# get a count of dictionary keys with values greater than some integer in python

Tags: python, dictionary, integer

I have a dictionary. The keys are words the value is the number of times those words occur.

```
countDict = {'house': 2, 'who': 41, 'joey': 409, 'boy': 2, 'girl':2}
```

I'd like to find out how many elements occur with a value of more than 1, with a value of more than 20 and with a value of more than 50.

I found this code

```
a = sum(1 for i in countDict if countDict.values() >= 2)
```

but I get an error that I'm guessing means that values in dictionaries can't be processed as integers.

```
builtin.TypeError: unorderable types: dict_values() >= int()
```

I tried modifying the above code to make the dictionary value be an integer but that did not work either.

```
a = sum(1 for i in countDict if int(countDict.values()) >= 2)

builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `a = sum(1 for i in countDict.values() if i >= 2)` you need to iterate over the values themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `collections.Counter` and a "classification function" to get the result in one-pass:

```
def classify(val):
    res = []
    if val > 1:
        res.append('> 1')
    if val > 20:
        res.append('> 20')
    if val > 50:
        res.append('> 50')
    return res

from collections import Counter

countDict = {'house': 2, 'who': 41, 'joey': 409, 'boy': 2, 'girl':2}
Counter(classification for val in countDict.values() for classification in classify(val))
# Counter({'> 1': 5, '> 20': 2, '> 50': 1})
```

Of course you can alter the return values or thresholds in case you want a different result.

---

But you were actually pretty close, you probably just mixed up the syntax - correct would be:

```
a = sum(1 for i in countDict.values() if i >= 2)
```

because you want to iterate over the `values()` and check the condition for each value.

What you got was an exception because the comparison between

```
>>> countDict.values()
dict_values([2, 409, 2, 41, 2])
```

and an integer like `2` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 7):

`countDict.items()` gives you key-value pairs in `countDict` so you can write:

```
>>> countDict = {'house': 2, 'who': 41, 'joey': 409, 'boy': 2, 'girl':2}
>>> [word for word, occurrences in countDict.items() if occurrences >= 20]
['who', 'joey']
```

If you just want the number of words, use `len`:

```
>>> countDict = {'house': 2, 'who': 41, 'joey': 409, 'boy': 2, 'girl':2}
>>> wordlist = [word for word, occurrences in countDict.items() if occurrences >= 20]
>>> len(wordlist)
2
```

Note that Python variables use lowercase and underscores (snake case): `count_dict` rather than `countDict`. By convention camel case is used for classes in Python:

```py
breakfast = SpamEggs()  # breakfast is new instance of class SpamEggs
lunch = spam_eggs()  # call function spam_eggs and store result in lunch
dinner = spam_eggs  # assign value of spam_eggs variable to dinner
```

See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You need this:

```
>>> countDict = {'house': 2, 'who': 41, 'joey': 409, 'boy': 2, 'girl':2}

>>> sum(1 for i in countDict.values() if i >= 2)
5
```

`values()` returns a **list** of all the values available in a given dictionary which means you can't convert the list to integer.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite close.  You just need to remember that `i` is accessible via the `if` statement.  I added all three examples to get you started.  Additionally, `values` creates a list of all values in the dictionary, which is not what you want, you instead want the currently evaluated value, `i`.

```
moreThan2 = sum(1 for i in countDict if countDict[i] >= 2)
moreThan20 = sum(1 for i in countDict if countDict[i] >= 20)
moreThan50 = sum(1 for i in countDict if countDict[i] >= 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .items() before applying your discrimination logic.

in -

```
for key, value in countDict.items():
  if value == 2: #edit for use
     print key
```

out -

```
house
boy
girl
```